# How often can I gain CP by talking in town?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

CP can be gained by talking to the NPCs in town. After some time passes, I can gain CP again this way.

How often may I gain CP in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may gain CP from talking in town 3 times per day. You can talk to 6 NPCs per refresh, per character (explained below).

It refreshes at 4:00 AM 12:00 PM and 8:00 PM Pacific Time.

---

At the top of the town screen you can see how mow many town NPCs are left for you to talk to.

You may also quickly switch between available characters by clicking on the refresh icon. This number will then change to the number of NPCs available for that character to talk to.

The order of switching is Bell -> Ais -> Lefiya

The next refresh, is shown in PST on the screen. This is the time when you will have more NPCs to talk to.

[image: Next Update]
In the above screenshot, I have 6 NPCs (max) available to talk to.

Answer (score 0):

At least 2-3 times a day.  I haven't timed it to see how often the refresh is, though.